# Can you format comments in PHP?

Tags: php, comments

I would like to be able to do things like bold or italicize text inside a PHP comment. Does anyone
know how to do this? For example:

```
// I want to bold **this**
```

Comment: PHPStorm, which does not seem to support this that I could find.

Answer (score 3):

If your editor supports formatting, by all means you can format your comments.

However, unless you're using Word to edit code (***extremely*** bad idea!) you're stuck with just plain old text.

Personally, if I ever need to emphasize text in a plain-text environment, I use `/italic/`, `*bold*` and `_underline_`. Incidentally, I believe these are the shortcuts for the same formatting in Word. Bonus!

Comment: This seems like a good solution. I was using *bold* but it really doesn't stand out like what I would like.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, source-code is plain text with no formatting normally in the PHP world (and most other programming languages). There are some "helpers":

- Editors sometimes highlight special text in special colors and allow you to click on things like for `@param` tags etc.
- PHPDocumentor allows you to place HTML tags inside your comments. Not all, but some. When the documentation is generated and you browse it with your browser, you will see your formattings - but not when you edit the code.
- For code editing you can do some special formattings like `_underline_` etc. - if you like it.

Answer (score 1):

It always depend on what you are using to read your code, I am using Eclipse IDE myself and there you can use

```php
/**
 * <div style="color: red; font-weight: heavy">Some text<br/>other line</div>
 * <strong>Now</strong> some &lt;tags&gt;
 */
```

However, it will be heavy reading with vim or most other editors.

#### EDIT:

So it really is just like real html and can be used like that.
However I personally dont recommend to use it as it breaks meaning of comments when reading same file with `less`, `notepad` or any editor that does not support html or css markup.

You can even do:

```php
/**
 * <style> div { margin: 10px; padding: 20px; background-color: #cde; } </style>
 * 
 * <div>Some text<br/>with background color, margin and padding</div>
 */
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. Does the IDE parse the HTML so you see "Some text" and "other line" without the HTML around it? And how is this heavy reading for other editors?

Comment: @Mike Yes, IDE parses it so it looks same as it will look when viewed with chrome, and it will be heavy reading if comment is full of tags...

Comment: What do you do if your comment actually contains HTML?

Comment: @Mike What do you do if your web page, stackoverflow for example, needs to show html? Use entities of course...

Comment: Well for someone who does a lot of work editing php/html I would sure hope that this feature can be disabled somehow. I often use PHP to comment out my HTML instead of the usual `<!--` `-->` so it's not visible to the browser.

Comment: @Mike this is only for PHPDoc so if you use /* Comment */ or // Comment, it is not parsed by IDE, and it is only parsed when viewed in PHPDoc way